# Multi branch pipeline jenkins job with [ci skip]

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have to skip some jenkins build based on git commit message. So I have searched and found [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ci+Skip+Plugin) jenkins plugin.But I could not configure **enable ci-skip** in multi branch pipeline job. This option is not available in multi branch pipeline setup.

Is there a way to configure this [ci skip] in multi branch jenkins pipeline?

Is it usable in jenkinsfile or Is it possible to prevent jenkins build based on commit message in jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 4):

You are not the only one experiencing problems with [ci skip]:

- [JENKINS-35509](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35509)
- [JENKINS-34130](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34130)

It looks like the plugin is yet broken.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your branch sources to poll your Git repository in your `multibranch pipeline`, you can **in theory** add an additional behaviour to ignore commits with certain messages, such as `[skip]`, as shown in the example below :

[image: Polling ignore commits]

I say "in theory" because I never could make that work, either on a `multibranch pipeline` job or on a `simple pipeline` job (with `pipeline script from SCM`).

Comment: I couldn't see this additional behaviours option in the multibranch pipeline job configuration. Is it need to install any jenkins plugin?

Comment: No need to install another plugin, you can find it in your `multibranch pipeline` configuration under `Branch Sources` > `Git` (after added with `Add Source` button) > `Additionnal Behaviours` -> `Add`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have configured bitbucket project source, so it doesn't appear in the branch sources. Is there anyway to configure the additional behaviours option in bitbucket sources?

Comment: I think you can use standard branch sources (i.e. not Gitbucket specific configuration) and then just put your Gitbucket repo URL as you would do with Github or custom Gitbucket.